# VLC command line volume control

Tags: terminal, vlc

I use VLC in command line mode on macOS and would like to set the volume from the command line as well. On a Linux system this can be achieved by using the option

`--alsa-gain= float value`

Note that

`--volume`

is deprecated. Does anyone know how to achieve volume control in macOS?

Comment: Was there *any* reference to the CLI documentation that referenced volume?  Usually when something is deprecated, it tells you what supersedes it.

Comment: I picked up on the volume option somewhere online. All VLC does when using volume is to display "Warning: option --volume no longer exists."

Comment: Try the *Official* Documentation:  https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above

`--gain= float number`

works, but beware that the float number has to be between 0 and 1 and not 0 and 8 as it is stated in the documentation linked above.